# How do i put headers in an api call?

Tags: javascript

I am making an api call to

http(s)://{hostaddress:port}/com.broadsoft.xsi-actions/v2.0/user/{userid}/services/callcenter

I have changed the appropriate information in the URL to reflect the correct host address/port / user id.

When that is complete, the page requests that I log on with a Username and Password.

I can manually enter this information, and receive the XML that I need. This is not Ideal. I would rather have a form that passess in this information.

To my understanding, this information is passed within the "headers". I have tried to look up how to do this, and even attempted using postman without much luck.  I am not sure how to do this.

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http(s)://{hostaddress:port}/com.broadsoft.xsi-actions/v2.0/user/{userid}/services/callcenter", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

per w3 schools I can use setRequestHeader() which adds a label/value pair to the header to be sent.

I have tried

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http(s)://{hostaddress:port}/com.broadsoft.xsi-actions/v2.0/user/{userid}/services/callcenter", true);
  xhttp.send();setRequestHeader(Username:myUserName,Password:myPassword);
}
```

with no resolution. once i get this working i will set up the form and pass in  the values.

Comment: `setRequestHeader` is a method of `XMLHttpRequest` prototype object, meaning that you use it like `xhttp.setRequestHeader(...)`. I am not sure what `Username:myUserName,Password:myPassword` is all about -- it's not valid JavaScript syntax I know of.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `setRequestHeader` in the wrong way and calling `send` before setting headers in any case.

Try with

```
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Username', myUserName); 
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Password', myPassword);
xhttp.send(); // only call send after setting up the headers
```

Comment: that seemingly gets me closer, now i have the CORS issue - from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

any suggestions for how to add the "allow origin"?

Comment: xhttp.setRequestHeader('Username', myUserName); 
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Password', myPassword);
xhttp.send();

does not work, i have used Post Man successfully,  and I enter Username and Password within the Authorization Tab, and connects without an issue.

Answer (score 1):

`xhttp.setRequestHeaders(name, value)` and it should be invoked before `xhttp.send()`. [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader)